# RemoteServiceException Caused by Handler after being called from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, handler

I uploaded an app on Google Play and saw some crashes happening to people that I couldn't recreate, the console website shows the following errors below, I'm using two Threads running at the same time and the handler it is supposedly crashing at is a simple

```java
private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
          g.setText("yes");
    };
}
```

is the issue with how im using the handler? is it causing leaks?

```
    android.app.RemoteServiceException:
        (ZygoteInit.java:873)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
        (ActivityThread.java:1768)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
        (Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop
        (Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main
        (ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
        (Native Method:0)
        (RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I also have this problem and I cannot replicate the error on my devices.